# 'objc/objc.h' file not found when trying to compile a objective-c program.What should I do?

Tags: objective-c, linux, oclint

If i use :

> oclint  test2.m -- -x objective-c -arch armv7 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc
>   -O0 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -g -I./Pods/Headers -c

or:

> oclint test2.m -- -c

It will show a Compiler Error:

> /usr/include/Foundation/Foundation.h:31:9: 'objc/objc.h' file not found

.

Comment: I hate to break the news to you, but file objc/objc.h was not found during the compilation

Comment: Well, thanks for sarcasm. How can I fix this?

Comment: <s>I hate to break the news to you, but</s> you should make sure the file is present where the compiler is looking for it. Your formulations lack any information which would allow us to deduce how to do it in your case, so you're better off checking the manuals for your compiler on how to emit diagnostic output or view/manage include paths.

Comment: Actually, there is plenty of information here.   (No, really, there is... I'll have to type it out in a bit).

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Actually, there are plenty of clues.  (1) Foundation.h was found, (2) this has the linux tag.  Therefore, if objc.h isn't found, then either the installation was bad/incomplete or the compiler's search paths are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you have `/usr/include/Foundation/Foundation.h:31:9: 'objc/objc.h' file not found` and you have `-isysroot /Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk` indicates that there is something weird about either that invocation line or in your install.

Start by building a standard dead simple Xcode project (you are on OS X w/Xcode, right?) and copy the compilation line out of the build, then modify accordingly.

Aha!  Missed the Linux tag, which provides even more context!  So... yeah... non-standard environment means you're gonna have to futz with the install and/or invocation until it works.

Comment: These are but general directions. It's not possible to suggest any more or less specific course of action. That's what I meant by "lacking information".